# How do I override a shared wagtail admin template?

Tags: wagtail

In wagtail currently a standard select is used for a one to many relation, and I'd like to override this to use a jquery UI autocomplete widget.

I found the template that renders the component in `wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html`, so I Thought that by following the [instructions](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html) I could override the template the way I would a base one, but unfortunately when I create `myapp/templates/wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html` it is not rendered in place of the base one. I did confirm that by creating `myapp/templates/wagtailadmin/base.html` that does get used.

How can I override this template short of editing the source?

Comment: 1) In your second filename you have `collection_choose` instead of `chooser` - is that a typo in your code, or just in this question? 2) In your INSTALLED_APPS list, does the app containing your custom template appear _above_ `wagtail.admin`?

Comment: thanks @gasman for the response. 1) Good catch, unfortunately just a typo in this question. 2) It does, I don't think the base.html override would work without it.

Comment: Isn't there a package that does this for you? https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-autocomplete

Comment: @allcaps thanks for the suggestion. while a good idea, doesn't appear to work outside of Page classes.

Comment: Wagtail autocomplete uses a hook on `insert_editror_js` and is pages only. If you need the whole admin you can try the `insert_global_admin_js` hook. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-autocomplete/blob/master/wagtailautocomplete/wagtail_hooks.py#L12 and http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/reference/hooks.html#insert-global-admin-js. I hope it helps.

Comment: @allcaps ah yes, that definitely made it usable - thanks!